# Is there a simple idiomatic way of updating key-value states in Redux reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux

If a redux app has a slice of state containing a key-value storage of objects, the correct pattern for updating it looks like this:

```
return {
    ...state,
    [id]: {
        ...state[id],
        valueIWantToChange: 'someValue',
    },
}
```

This is due to the immutability of redux and the need to copy all the data.

For nested reducers of known keys, using `combineReducers` allows one to specify nested bits of state which have their own isolated code, simplifying it.

There is no way that I know to simplify writing reducers for a key-value object though. In a state like the example above, every single reducer will need to have the boilerplate code of using spread operators to copy the state, and then the specific `id` we want to update, and then the state inside that `id`, and then finally we can update a value in our state.

I find this very tedious to write, and the resulting code unnecessarily bloated, especially when compared with mutable frameworks like Vue where one would just write `state[id].valueIWantToChange = 'someValue';`

Is there any existing solution or other way of making this type of reducer simpler to write?

Comment: are you looking for immutaibility helpers https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js?

Comment: You could have a look at https://github.com/immerjs/immer which allows writing your reducers with mutations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the official Redux Toolkit, which is the official recommended way of writing *any* Redux logic (for two years now) and brings a `createReducer` and `createSlice` api that allow you to just write mutating statements inside those reducers.

`createSlice` also auto-generates action creators and makes type string constants obsolete.

Such a "slice" would look like this:

```
const initialState = []

const todosSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'todos',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    todoAdded(state, action) {
      // ✅ This "mutating" code is okay inside of createSlice!
      state.push(action.payload)
    },
    todoToggled(state, action) {
      const todo = state.find(todo => todo.id === action.payload)
      todo.completed = !todo.completed
    },
    todosLoading(state, action) {
      // you can still use old-style immutable updates if you want to
      return {
        ...state,
        status: 'loading'
      }
    }
  }
})

// autogenerated action creators
export const { todoAdded, todoToggled, todosLoading } = todosSlice.actions

export default todosSlice.reducer
```

For a quick overview, take a look at [the last chapter of the "Redux Fundamentals" tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux)

For a deeper introduction, read the [full "Redux Essentials" tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts)

Comment: This is really nice, from the fundamentals link you provided: "Immer tracks all the changes you've tried to make, and then uses that list of changes to return a safely immutably updated value" (...) "You can only write "mutating" logic in Redux Toolkit's `createSlice` and `createReducer` because they use Immer inside!"

Answer (score 0):

For a lighter solution if you don't want to add dependencies (which some projects can't afford), I chose to implement simple helpers that only take a few lines of code. [This article](https://dev.to/klis87/killing-bad-parts-of-redux-say-goodbye-to-boilerplate-48ho) helped me get a food starting point for simplifying everything.

Here is some example TypeScript code you can put in a helper file and then use to write actions/reducers much more succintly without adding heavy dependencies.

```js
import { AnyAction } from 'redux'

// Helpers for creating actions, can use version with payload if all your actions have a payload parameter, or a more generic one

export type ActionFunction = (payload: any) => AnyAction
export type FunctionWithString<T extends Function> = T & string
export interface ActionWithPayload<T = any> extends AnyAction {
  payload: T
}
export type ActionCreator<T = any> = FunctionWithString<(payload: T) => ActionWithPayload<T>>

export function createPayloadAction<T>(name: string): ActionCreator<T> {
  const actionCreator = (payload: T) => ({
    type: name,
    payload,
  })
  actionCreator.toString = () => name
  return (actionCreator as any) as ActionCreator<T>
}

export function createAction<T>(name: string, actionFunction: ActionFunction): ActionCreator<T> {
  const actionCreator = (payload: T) => ({
    type: name,
    payload: actionFunction(payload),
  })
  actionCreator.toString = () => name
  return (actionCreator as any) as ActionCreator<T>
}

// The shape of your reducer functions, makes it easier to deal with having all reducers deal with the same payload-based action format
export type MyReducer<S, A = any> = (state: S, payload: A) => S

export interface ReducersMap<S> {
  [key: string]: MyReducer<S>
}

export function createReducer<S>(reducers: ReducersMap<S>, defaultState: S) {
  return (state: S, action: ActionWithPayload) => {
    if (!state) {
      return defaultState
    }
    const reducer = reducers[action.type]

    if (reducer) {
      return reducer(state, action.payload)
    }

    return state
  }
}


// Common use case helpers for reducers

type KeyValueState<T> = { [key: string]: T }
// Updates a specific value key in a reducer that is shaped like a key-value object
export function keyValueUpdateReducer<T>(
  state: KeyValueState<T>,
  id: string,
  value: Partial<T>,
): KeyValueState<T> {
  return {
    ...state,
    [id]: {
      ...state[id],
      ...value,
    },
  }
}

// Update a specific value in a reducer that is shaped like a key-value object
export function keyValueSetReducer<T>(
  state: KeyValueState<T>,
  id: string,
  value: T,
): KeyValueState<T> {
  return {
    ...state,
    [id]: value,
  }
}
```

Example use:

`action`

```js
import { createPayloadAction } from './helpers'

export interface SetAThingPayload {
  id: string
  thing: any
}
export const setAThing = createPayloadAction<SetAThingPayload('SET_A_THING')
```

`reducer`

```js
import { createReducer, keyValueSetReducer, keyValueUpdateReducer } from './helpers'
import { setAThing } from './actions'

export const thingsReducer = createReducer<MyAppState>(
  {
    [setAThing]: (state, { id, thing }) => keyValueSetReducer(state, id, thing),
  },
  {},
)
```